# How to establish contact with DX100 controller via ROS interface

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to setup contact with DX100 controller from Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.
So far we've:

- Installed ROS Groovy desktop-full
- Installed industrial core and motoman(including motoman driver, not dx100) packages from source(cloned groovy branch from github, not SVN repo).
- Updated controller with latest software, v.3.53xxxx-14
- Tried to goto the controller webpage without success. Connected via ethernet and entered "http://robot_ip:8080" in web browser.

Haven't performed any MotoPLUS configuration since we were told all -14 versions had support for MotoPLUS. Is this correct or do we need to install MotoPLUS or INFORM Code according to tutorial?
If yes, how do we transfer these files into the controller?

We were not able to perform step 5 in the server application tutorial. Changed to Management mode and tried to enable #82015, according to the steps but this wasn't possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85381/how-to-establish-contact-with-dx100-controller-via-ros-interface/) by [plundgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7261/plundgren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like the controller is not configured. I recommend calling Motoman support. They should be able to help.

You typically need to install the server on the controller, unless Motoman did that for you.

Motoman will help you verify the server is running (there are special status IO that tell you this). Once this is done and you can ping the controller from the ROS PC, then you should be able to connect with the launch files as described in the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0